# Problems with laptop screen, distorted with colored horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: laptop, display

From time to time, my laptop screen gets all distorted. It's split in 2 sections with random horizontal and vertical lines all across it. I have been facing this problem since the past month. After I switch it off and turn it back on in about an hour's time, the problem seems to resolve itself on it's own. What could I be dealing with here? Also noteworthy, I tried screenshoting the screen(when distorted) and pasting it on word to know how it looked like, the screenshot came out all fine with no signs of distortion where infact what I could see on my screen were colored lines.
[image]

Comment: Best guess: hardware failure in the LCD or in the cables to the LCD. If it is still under warrenty then boot from a liveCD, show that is is not an OS problem, call HP and let them repair it. If not under warranty connect an external screen. I expect that to work fine (which would confirm the problem is in the output to the LCD or the LCD itself). Open the laptop, unplug and replug the cables to the LCD. Then test again.

Answer (score 1):

Test the laptop on an external screen to see if any issues happen. If not the screen has been damaged. If so, the video card is failing(sometimes it can be replaced but only on rather high end laptops. Most times it is a part of the board.).